# I want to display an circled image. I want a full circle with image. i know to achieve this i need border-radius

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

i tried with border-radius: 50%, i don`t get a full circled images

```
<Picture>
  <ProfileImage alt="test" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260"></ProfileImage>
</Picture>

const Picture = styled.div`
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
background-color: blue;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
`;
const ProfileImage = styled.img`
border-radius: 50%;
width: 70%;
`;
```

What i get:
[image]

Comment: You have to make the image **square** first.

Comment: Can you set width and height same size

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to instead use a div, sized to be square (equal height & width), set the image as background image to cover div.

- `background-size: cover;` maintains original aspect ratio, i.e. no stretching
- `background-position: center;` centers the image in the circle

```
const ProfileImage = styled.div`
  background-image: ${({ src }) => `url(${src})`};
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
`;
```

[image]

[image: Edit wispy-frog-fks4j]

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep same with and height we can rely on `padding-top` set in percents: *% - Specifies a top padding in percent of the width of the element* ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-top.asp)). So when you want 70% width square image, you can set `padding-top: 70%` together with `height: 0` and it will result into square where you can put the image as a background and use `border-radius` on it.

```
<Picture>
   <ProfileImage backgroundUrl="https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" />
</Picture>

const Picture = styled.div`
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: blue;
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
`;

const ProfileImage = styled.div`
   width: 70%;
   height: 0;
   padding-top: 70%;
   background-image: ${({ backgroundUrl }) => `url("${backgroundUrl}")`};
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   border-radius: 50%;
`;
```